# Relationship between R-matrix and Casimir element?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Given a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, is there any relation between its Casimir element and the $R$-matrix of the related Yangian $Y(\mathfrak{g})$?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.08162 : the answer is yes and this is explained, at least from one perspective, therein. I hope to have time to write a proper answer soon.